# Does boost::bimap takes more memory as compared to 2 std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++

Here's the pseudo code

```
boost::bimap<int,int> bMap;
std::unordered_map<int, int> m1;
std::unordered_map<int, int> m2;
```

Will bMap take more memory as compared to m1 and m2 combined?

Comment: Pretty hard to say, considering `std::unordered_map` internals as implementation-specific, and may grow in different speed then `boost::bimap`. I'd say go with `bimap` as it's more convenient to use, but if you really care about memory measure it yourself for your use case.

Comment: How do you measure memory usage? `sizeof`? Or, maxRSS?

Comment: Hi @DanielLangr
I am measuring memory usgae using maxRSS.